# Power Automate (Flow) Get Cell From Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, power-automate

I'm looking to automate a process using Power Automate:

1. User opens a form (built in MS Forms) and enters some figures
2. Flow takes these figures and adds them to a spreadsheet stored on OneDrive (with date & time)
3. The spreadsheet performs calculations on the data
4. Flow then waits 30 seconds (to give the spreadsheet time to perform calculations)
5. Flow gets the calculation (column called 'Multiple') from the spreadsheet and if it falls between two values, sends a warning to a Teams chat.

I have got the flow to do 1-4 but I'm struggling with 5. Things I've tried:

- List Rows Present in a Table, then compose adding `last(body('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['value'])`
- List Rows Present in a Table, applying an Order By `Date, Time Desc`, choosing the top 1 rows

Obviously I've no idea what I'm doing and have taken the above from the internet via search engine results.

I need to return the last row and return a value from it. I may need to get other values from other columns at some point too so it'd be handy to know how to extract anything and I can just apply the logic to get this last record.
Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

This is the output from the list_rows...

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "headers": {
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked",
    "Vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "x-ms-request-id": "6a5e4583-ba65-47f7-9acd-44e3833e14f8;e387566b-9dd6-4916-b749-34f5e4a666ad;e6a2af19-cab5-4d23-b0e4-446f9383411d;492ea8b3-4aa9-4703-82ce-8214cee0d287",
    "OData-Version": "4.0",
    "Strict-Transport-Security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
    "X-Content-Type-Options": "nosniff",
    "X-Frame-Options": "DENY",
    "Timing-Allow-Origin": "*",
    "x-ms-apihub-cached-response": "true",
    "x-ms-apihub-obo": "true",
    "Cache-Control": "no-store, no-cache",
    "Date": "Mon, 23 May 2022 10:47:50 GMT",
    "Content-Type": "application/json; odata.metadata=minimal; odata.streaming=true",
    "Expires": "-1",
    "Content-Length": "7785"
  },
  "body": {
    "@odata.context": "https://excelonline-ukw.logic-ase-ukwest.p.azurewebsites.net/$metadata#drives('b%21gfFR-ZV53U-aCUKgEmMbVA4tJoGJWBNHlsM4s2Mc51jO-ENEU1S-Rq63C1uxVytI')/Files('01OPLUCDQHJ7VCPJB5FRD2CAOAKEFV2N7S')/Tables('%7B48F61074-8C66-4AF5-B0F9-6E19B6902C96%7D')/items",
    "value": [
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "710c9d6c-94ea-4c2d-a7a4-3b3ae77e16d6",
        "Date": "44698.6458449074",
        "Time": "44698.6458449074",
        "g/l ni": "4",
        "ECV808Ha": "5",
        "Multiple": "20"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "d6a51bf4-6124-479b-801a-fd064c9e60bf",
        "Date": "44698.6492824074",
        "Time": "44698.6492824074",
        "g/l ni": "5",
        "ECV808Ha": "15",
        "Multiple": "75"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "041e248b-24aa-48cd-8b56-f7b034ebcac0",
        "Date": "44698.6550578704",
        "Time": "44698.6550578704",
        "g/l ni": "5.2",
        "ECV808Ha": "4.8",
        "Multiple": "24.96"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "9bd74e5c-ab80-4441-ac79-68cf960bcb2b",
        "Date": "44698.6656597222",
        "Time": "44698.6656597222",
        "g/l ni": "4",
        "ECV808Ha": "45",
        "Multiple": "180"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "a506830f-2ce0-4d68-ad40-cdc8e8b6f2d8",
        "Date": "44699.6349884259",
        "Time": "44699.6349884259",
        "g/l ni": "8.6",
        "ECV808Ha": "9.3",
        "Multiple": "79.98"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "5c946cba-d923-4abd-b4e2-747ef4d26c61",
        "Date": "44699.6391435185",
        "Time": "44699.6391435185",
        "g/l ni": "15.2",
        "ECV808Ha": "8.2",
        "Multiple": "124.64"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "cfb77053-0587-48c2-8e25-2bfe4130667a",
        "Date": "44699.6422337963",
        "Time": "44699.6422337963",
        "g/l ni": "14.2",
        "ECV808Ha": "18.6",
        "Multiple": "264.12"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "6d1f27e7-18d7-4686-9610-5e4cf8eb18bf",
        "Date": "44699.6454976852",
        "Time": "44699.6454976852",
        "g/l ni": "8.2",
        "ECV808Ha": "2.6",
        "Multiple": "21.32"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "9799d5d1-0a05-4a92-b8a3-26a2e795b460",
        "Date": "44699.6517824074",
        "Time": "44699.6517824074",
        "g/l ni": "15",
        "ECV808Ha": "15.2",
        "Multiple": "228"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "bb58c18a-1b10-418b-9782-7fc9cc2d7bf0",
        "Date": "44699.6672453704",
        "Time": "44699.6672453704",
        "g/l ni": "14",
        "ECV808Ha": "12.2",
        "Multiple": "170.8"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "ef60df80-9658-4e5b-bb03-4176e43670eb",
        "Date": "44699.6729166667",
        "Time": "44699.6729166667",
        "g/l ni": "15",
        "ECV808Ha": "16",
        "Multiple": "240"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "1e1d1f61-cc7d-4a6d-ac6e-3f3ad38def5d",
        "Date": "44699.6741319444",
        "Time": "44699.6741319444",
        "g/l ni": "12.2",
        "ECV808Ha": "13.4",
        "Multiple": "163.48"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "e780c125-3199-4360-854f-f3ef01944225",
        "Date": "44700.502962963",
        "Time": "44700.502962963",
        "g/l ni": "4",
        "ECV808Ha": "2.5",
        "Multiple": "10"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "40319bdb-8923-4149-908c-7d2e10f8555b",
        "Date": "44700.5053356482",
        "Time": "44700.5053356482",
        "g/l ni": "5",
        "ECV808Ha": "8",
        "Multiple": "40"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "3ce6dbf0-919f-4ae7-9a90-483c18382b1a",
        "Date": "44700.527650463",
        "Time": "44700.527650463",
        "g/l ni": "4.5",
        "ECV808Ha": "8.6",
        "Multiple": "38.7"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "3afffdaf-7b2e-4c5a-9407-aa20dedaf1db",
        "Date": "44700.5286111111",
        "Time": "44700.5286111111",
        "g/l ni": "8.5",
        "ECV808Ha": "4.2",
        "Multiple": "35.7"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "312b51be-1fb8-4b5e-ab0c-d0584ce0a947",
        "Date": "44700.5975",
        "Time": "44700.5975",
        "g/l ni": "8",
        "ECV808Ha": "14",
        "Multiple": "112"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "8ffbff5c-c94c-4681-830f-07898984e2dd",
        "Date": "44700.6011689815",
        "Time": "44700.6011689815",
        "g/l ni": "4",
        "ECV808Ha": "8",
        "Multiple": "32"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "a02f1621-c007-483a-982e-e16520135adb",
        "Date": "44700.6019675926",
        "Time": "44700.6019675926",
        "g/l ni": "4",
        "ECV808Ha": "2.5",
        "Multiple": "10"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "3afcc248-15e1-4bdf-911c-baa2531d9c01",
        "Date": "44700.6034837963",
        "Time": "44700.6034837963",
        "g/l ni": "4.5",
        "ECV808Ha": "5.25",
        "Multiple": "23.625"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "bb09f769-5244-410d-8883-ee79e2931487",
        "Date": "44700.6041435185",
        "Time": "44700.6041435185",
        "g/l ni": "80",
        "ECV808Ha": "2.5",
        "Multiple": "200"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "59335733-aae0-48c0-b1db-d9f165ea20a9",
        "Date": "44700.6059722222",
        "Time": "44700.6059722222",
        "g/l ni": "4",
        "ECV808Ha": "2.5",
        "Multiple": "10"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "5ed3abf6-167a-4eaf-92f2-8d2b1905430b",
        "Date": "44700.6153125",
        "Time": "44700.6153125",
        "g/l ni": "8",
        "ECV808Ha": "6",
        "Multiple": "48"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "c78052c0-0c39-40d4-aa59-cb47a1cf087b",
        "Date": "44700.645",
        "Time": "44700.645",
        "g/l ni": "4",
        "ECV808Ha": "2.5",
        "Multiple": "10"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "25cce007-95ef-46d5-b358-1170099cf116",
        "Date": "44700.6467939815",
        "Time": "44700.6467939815",
        "g/l ni": "4",
        "ECV808Ha": "4.5",
        "Multiple": "18"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "40850a3b-4fa8-4a8b-955c-7ae455275d2a",
        "Date": "44700.6484027778",
        "Time": "44700.6484027778",
        "g/l ni": "8",
        "ECV808Ha": "6.2",
        "Multiple": "49.6"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "bdf7718c-04fe-4734-87e0-919e24d2c0ca",
        "Date": "44700.6496412037",
        "Time": "44700.6496412037",
        "g/l ni": "6",
        "ECV808Ha": "6",
        "Multiple": "36"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "ebc60adc-80a1-4c40-b5a1-970e7845a679",
        "Date": "44701.382662037",
        "Time": "44701.382662037",
        "g/l ni": "4",
        "ECV808Ha": "5",
        "Multiple": "20"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "14ef1d2a-4479-46d5-9f1f-9efc489ef91a",
        "Date": "44701.4095486111",
        "Time": "44701.4095486111",
        "g/l ni": "5",
        "ECV808Ha": "5.5",
        "Multiple": "27.5"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "d644b688-8e91-4f81-a4f4-d63650b1837e",
        "Date": "44701.414837963",
        "Time": "44701.414837963",
        "g/l ni": "8",
        "ECV808Ha": "6",
        "Multiple": "48"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "749cb9ee-1214-4154-8c17-9f6de606efe8",
        "Date": "44701.4172337963",
        "Time": "44701.4172337963",
        "g/l ni": "8",
        "ECV808Ha": "65",
        "Multiple": "520"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "22266488-3477-4b10-9670-71b529d20a24",
        "Date": "44701.4225115741",
        "Time": "44701.4225115741",
        "g/l ni": "4",
        "ECV808Ha": "6",
        "Multiple": "24"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "2afa89ca-33d0-4689-b1ba-796ee73ef517",
        "Date": "44701.4230439815",
        "Time": "44701.4230439815",
        "g/l ni": "4",
        "ECV808Ha": "8",
        "Multiple": "32"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "d19bda68-b5ee-4785-88c2-e5ff607fb972",
        "Date": "44701.4236458333",
        "Time": "44701.4236458333",
        "g/l ni": "8",
        "ECV808Ha": "90",
        "Multiple": "720"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "52dc3cf9-fae0-4ab7-ba12-70bcaaf2ebf5",
        "Date": "44701.4238425926",
        "Time": "44701.4238425926",
        "g/l ni": "8",
        "ECV808Ha": "60",
        "Multiple": "480"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "23978938-312a-4f8f-be6d-be7c9b9ec070",
        "Date": "44701.4204513889",
        "Time": "44701.4204513889",
        "g/l ni": "4",
        "ECV808Ha": "5",
        "Multiple": "20"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "337fefdb-3cb4-4b36-a38b-4676f4037896",
        "Date": "44701.4305787037",
        "Time": "44701.4305787037",
        "g/l ni": "18",
        "ECV808Ha": "16",
        "Multiple": "288"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "9bca489c-fa39-44d7-adff-6a4520fbb526",
        "Date": "44704.3115046296",
        "Time": "44704.3115046296",
        "g/l ni": "4",
        "ECV808Ha": "8",
        "Multiple": "32"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "b00a9901-1f45-41b5-b14b-a0f78eced0e0",
        "Date": "44704.4353240741",
        "Time": "44704.4353240741",
        "g/l ni": "6",
        "ECV808Ha": "525",
        "Multiple": "3150"
      },
      {
        "@odata.etag": "",
        "ItemInternalId": "1ef7b9c0-e575-424c-9939-d59aa19f4944",
        "Date": "44704.4497337963",
        "Time": "44704.4497337963",
        "g/l ni": "5",
        "ECV808Ha": "6",
        "Multiple": "30"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot showing the cell(s) you want to return? Also, is it always the same set of cells? Can it be set to a named range? To make it easier for the calling application?

Comment: Did you get an error because if I do exactly what you've listed, I can get the table from the table and also easily retrieve the last row.

Comment: @Skin I've added a screenshot to show what is happening.

Comment: Cool, but now you need to show us the expression in the condition action, that’s what it’s conplaining about.

Comment: @Skin ah yes, apologies. Have added another.

Comment: Can you provide the JSON from the `List_rows_present_in_a_table` action?  I'd say you shouldn't need a `Compose` out of that for what you're doing.  It likely needs to be a variable if anything.

Comment: @Skin I've added a screenshot of what is output from the List_rows action.

Comment: Can you provide it in the question?  I can't do much with that unfortunately, I need to interrogate it.  Sorry man!  just trying to help.

Comment: @Skin yes, I know you are ... and I do appreciate it. I've added the actual text to the original question.

Comment: Which value are you wanting to see if it's greater than 10 in the condition?  There are three, is it ... `g/l ni`, `ECV808Ha` or `Multiple`?

Comment: It is the value created by 'Multiple'. There is a chance that I'll be trying to extract other values further down the line though, so it'd be handy to know how to reference different cells/values.

Comment: Did we get there?  :-)

Comment: @Skin unfortunately not. I was out of the office from Monday lunchtime but I'm back in now. I'm still getting the parse error saying it is invalid JSON.

Comment: You need to put the expression (i.e. *last(body('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['value'])*) in the **Expression** tab, not directly in the **Dynamic Content** tab when pasting it into the  **Parse JSON** step.  Does that make sense?  If not, put your cursor into the `Content` field and see what I mean.  I can tell because your screenshot doesn't have an @ in front of `last(` ...

Comment: @Skin Huzzah!!!! It worked :) I get it now. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to easily refer to any of the fields from the `last` item in the array from the Excel table, you should use a `Parse JSON` action but you should pass in an example object to set the schema.

That will generate the dynamic content that you can refer to at any subsequent step in the process.

[image: Flow]

If I pass an example object in to define the schema that looks like this ...

```
{
  "@odata.etag": "",
  "ItemInternalId": "4b329100-49e6-41ef-8ae0-a5ecaf82f8f6",
  "Date": "44704.44973",
  "Time": "44704.44973",
  "g/l ni": "5",
  "ECV808Ha": "6",
  "Multiple": "30"
}
```

... the schema comes out like this ...

```
{
    "properties": {
        "@@odata.etag": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Date": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "ECV808Ha": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "ItemInternalId": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Multiple": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "Time": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "g/l ni": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "type": "object"
}
```

... and the expression to populate the content is as you had in relation to getting the last item ...

```
last(body('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['value'])
```

... so that helps you with the **any field** part of your question.

When it comes to the condition, this is what will work for you ...

[image: Condition]

The expression on the left had side is ...

```
float(body('Parse_JSON')?['Multiple'])
```

I need to encapsulate it in the `float()` function so it turns it into a number.

From there, I get a result where the comparison will be determined.

For the last value in your table, it evaluates to true.

[image: Result]

Comment: I'm getting the following error... InvalidJSON. The 'content' property of actions of type 'ParseJson' must be valid JSON. The provided value cannot be parsed: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: l. Path '', line 0, position 0.'.

Comment: Paste your expression here as a comment that you used in the *content* field.

Comment: "content": "last(body('List_rows_present_in_a_table')?['value'])", (this is in the JSON raw inputs section)

Comment: Right’o, next thing, add a screenshot of the Parse JSON action as you have it in your flow definition.

Comment: I'll add it to the main question. I need to leave for the day now but will pick up again when I'm back in office on Wednesday.  I appreciate your help.